# Complex query using Criteria API in Hibernate 4

Tags: java, hibernate, criteria

I am using hibernate 4 with criteria API and I am facing a complex query.

My relational model is the following:

[image: relational model]

What I am trying to do is to get for a given Person all the shipped **Articles** that belongs to the "n" last `ShoppingEvent` before a specified date.

How can I achieve that using criteria API?

*n.b.* I already tried something like:

```
ProjectionList properties = Projections.projectionList();
properties.add(Projections.property("article.articleId"), "articleId");
properties.add(Projections.property("article.price"), "price");
properties.add(Projections.property("article.type"), "type");

return session.createCriteria(Person.class)//
         .add(Restrictions.idEq(person.getPersonId()))//
         .createAlias("articles", "article")//
         .createAlias("article.shoppingEvent", "se")//
         .add(Restrictions.le("se.date", currentDate))//
         .addOrder(Order.desc("se.date"))//
         .setProjection(properties)//
         .setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(Articles.class))//
         .list();
```

Which returns the articles I want but I don't succeed to use the `setMaxResults` to limit the max number of `ShoppingEvents`.

Comment: What do you mean by "I can't get it to use the setMaxResults" ? Do you have an error ? Or you add it and it doesn't apply and returns more than your maxResults ?

Comment: Thank you for replying, I mean I get the "n" last Articles but not all the Articles of the last "n" ShoppingEvent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to try a DetachedCriteria, have it return the ids of your "n" last ShoppingEvent and then in your criteria you add a restriction that your article.shoppingEvent must match the list of ids from your detachedCriteria.

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier if you build your query based on the Article, it would be like this:

```
ProjectionList properties = Projections.projectionList();
properties.add(Projections.property("id"), "articleId");
properties.add(Projections.property("price"), "price");
properties.add(Projections.property("type"), "type");

return session.createCriteria(Article.class) 
 .createAlias("person", "person") 
 .createAlias("shoppingEvent", "shoppingEvent") 
         .add(Restrictions.idEq(person.getPersonId()))  
         .add(Restrictions.le("shoppingEvent.date", currentDate)) 
         .addOrder(Order.desc("shoppingEvent.date")) 
         .setProjection(properties) 
         .setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(Articles.class)) 
         .setMaxResults(1)
         .uniqueResult();
```

> I mean I get the "n" last Articles but not all the Articles of the
>   last "n" ShoppingEvent

To do this just specify "n" in the **.setMaxResults( n )**

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I had to modify my mapping that was inconsistent to do that (I added the relation @ManyToOne person in the Article entity, that wasn't there before). But even with this I only get the last "n" Articles. But what I want to retrieve is **all** the Article of the last "n" **ShoppingEvent**